# Creating picture gallery with the help of table in html

Tags: html, css, image, html-table, row

i have a picture below and i want to design a layout like this with the help of table in HTML

[image: Click for the image]

Comment: I recommend that you make an attempt, then let us know what you tried and where specifically you got stuck. Please see How do [I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This doesn't look like table data - are you constrained to try to use table?

Comment: @AHaworth yes i have to do it with a table

Comment: That is a pity because grid is very suitable - table absolutely isn't. Can you talk with whoever set that constraint or is it a system necessity?

Comment: As you have to use table, you could start by using it to create a 5x5 grid - 5 cells in each of 5 rows and make them square. Then position images as backgrounds to pseudo elements spanning more than their 'owning' element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a couple of ideas to get you started.

This snippet first creates the 'gallery' using CSS grid and then using a table.

The grid property lets you start/end an item wherever you want in terms of row and column.

The items can overlap and to make sure the little square in the center is above everything else it's given a z-index 1.

Grid would be my preferred method, but as you have to use table, the second part creates a 5 cell by 5 cell table and then puts a background image on various pseudo elements which are positioned at the start of the relevant cell, but in some cases are twice or three times the width.

It's not what table is designed for, but in the past we had to use it to get round formatting issues.

```html
<style>
            * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  
  .gallery {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-columns: 20vmin;
    grid-auto-rows: 20vmin;
    grid-gap: 0px;
  }
  
  .pic {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
  }
  
  .pic:nth-child(1) {
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300); grid-column: 1 / 3; grid-row: 1 / 3; }
 .pic:nth-child(2) {
      background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1016/200/300); grid-column: 3 / 6; grid-row: 1 / 4; }
 .pic:nth-child(3) {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1018/200/300); grid-column: 3 ; grid-row: 3; z-index: 1;}
 .pic:nth-child(4) {
          background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1019/200/300); grid-column: 1 / 4; grid-row: 3 / 6; }
 .pic:nth-child(5) {
            background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1021/200/300); grid-column: 4 / 6; grid-row: 4 / 6; }
</style>
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="pic">1</div>
  <div class="pic">2</div>
  <div class="pic">3</div>
  <div class="pic">4</div>
  <div class="pic">5</div>
</div>
<style>
.tablegallery {
    border-style: collapse;
  }
  
  .tablegallery,
  .tablegallery *,
  .tablegallery *::before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: collapse;
  }
  
  .tablegallery tr td {
    --w: 20vmin;
    width: var(--w);
    height: var(--w);
    display: inline-flex;
  }
  
  .tablegallery tr td {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .tablegallery tr td::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-flex;
  }
  
  .tablegallery tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)::before {
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/300);
    width: calc(2 * var(--w));
    height: calc(2 * var(--w));
  }
  
  .tablegallery tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3)::before {
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1016/200/300);
    width: calc(3 * var(--w));
    height: calc(3 * var(--w));
  }
  
  .tablegallery tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(3)::before {
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1018/500/300);
    width: calc(1 * var(--w));
    height: calc(1 * var(--w));
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .tablegallery tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(1)::before {
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1019/200/300);
    width: calc(3 * var(--w));
    height: calc(3 * var(--w));
  }
  
  .tablegallery tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(4)::before {
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1021/200/300);
    width: calc(2 * var(--w));
    height: calc(2 * var(--w));
  }
}
</style>
<table class="tablegallery">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```